# In less: how to enter as search pattern '(#'

Tags: regular-expression, less

Im less, version 590, I can enter as search pattern `\(` to search for an open parenthesis.

And I can enter `#` (hash character) to search for this.

But when I have to search for both two characters, open parenthesis followed by hash character, I cannot accomplish this.

How can I input this?

Answer (score 2):

From [less manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html), we understand that :

> The pattern is a regular expression, as recognized by the regular
> expression library supplied by your system.

[Whatever the library supplied, parentheses are special characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards) that should be escaped when needed as a literal by the mean of an immediately preceding backslash.
Within `less`, you then might find your way keying :

```
/\(#
```

Comment: Quite natural. But that did not work (othewise I had not asked). Regards.

Comment: @AntonWessel : Then please post what *less -V* outputs. At the right of the version number should the regular expression library used be displayed. As on mine : *less 608 (PCRE2 regular expressions)*

Comment: there was a typo: in my question you should read: one backslash and left paranthesi, open bracket "\\(" --  your editor behaves differently in title  vs normal txt.

Comment: more in detail: the behavior of your buggy editor differs for title vs body.

Comment: Your requirement to post what less outputs: (a) less --version shows:

Comment: (a) less --version shows "less 590 (GNU regular expression) --- this output is not usable since my installed regex libraries are used by verious installed utilities in quite a different way, and some of them depending on options I give.   -----  (b) output of echo ""(#)" | less; and then for searching I type: "\\(#".  Today the pattern is accepted, is working. --- this means now all ok. I don' know why some days ago in very many trials I had the problems. --- But in meantime I have often tried to install a new less version 602 wh bug with color and -R fixed. Yet 602 is only avalible in source.

Answer (score 0):

`less` treats its search strings as extended regular expressions. On top of that as seen if `man less`, `!`, `*` and `@` are treated specially if entered at the start.

So, all 3 (and some control characters) plus all the characters that are special in the ERE syntax (`$^*()+{}.?\|`) need to be escaped if they're to be taken literally.

Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> (one of those control characters to switch from a regex matching to a substring search. You'll see the prompt will change from `/` to `Regex-off /`.

The `!`, `@`, `*` (and ^R and other control characters) are still special at the start though.